# Strange noise from engine on Ford Focus

Tags: engine, ford, noise

I have a strange noise coming from the engine on a 2018 Ford Focus SE, under 50k miles still. Have had it repaired at the dealership due to oil pump blowing up essentially, bunch of other issues with it still RPMs drop (shown in my other question) and stalling to name a couple. It sounds loud and bad in general but there's also this strange noise hard to describe kinda like an angry cat purring, video of the sound linked below.

[Video 1](https://streamable.com/qc8mm9)

[Video 2](https://streamable.com/w2e7jx)

I am taking it back once again soon, just want to be prepared and be able to put it on paper of what could be the issues encase they keep up the "it's good" attitude.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like an issue with the camshaft.  When the gap between the camshaft lobes and the cam follower is to big, you get that slapping noise as the cam hits the follower.  This could be caused by a number of reasons, depending on which engine you have.  The most likely I would say is that the hydraulic lifter on one of the lobes is faulty and not taking up the gap correctly.